# Programming 3d Games in Java

Tags: java

Hi I started this summer to learn Java because I was interessted in creating games.I managed to get a firm grasp of Java SE core and now I wana move further in creating some 3D games the only problem is I dont know where to start.

Can you guys recomend me some books that help me understad 3d game development in Java better?

Answer (score 8):

This can be a good place to start

http://jmonkeyengine.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use OGRE wrapper for java!

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Ogre4j

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Java Lightweight Game Library](http://www.lwjgl.org/)

There are some pretty good tutorials using JOGL (Open GL)